# How can Temari live with Shikamaru?

Tags: naruto

Currently, I was watching the "Boruto: Naruto Next generation" series and I saw the scene where Temari and Shikamaru were talking to each other now that they are married. Now, it kind of got me wondering: don't all the village (Hidden Sand, Hidden Leaf, Hidden Mist, etc.) strictly forbid villager from coming out of their village, just so they can keep the village's secret?

Comment: Wars change things, ppl, politics, rules, authors, staff, etc.

Comment: Temari is Sand Village Ambassador since the events in Part I

Comment: When you think about it, the show never addresses "immigration" explicitly. Either you are part of your home village, a defect, an alliance (Senju and Uzumaki), or a rogue ninja. Temari marrying someone from another village and being able to become a permanent resident in Konoha semms to be unprecedented.

Comment: after the war the five nation came together and are in peace with each other, they hold regular Kage meetings and exchange information. I don't think they have the old rules now. as we see in the Boruto anime, their world is moving towards science and away from Shinobi. the kids don't even know what Chakra is :|

Comment: Adding on to what the other guys said, I think Naruto has a big part in this cultural change. He's a leading figure in the movement for peace. Even the head of the Hyuga clan(who were hell-bent on keeping their clan secrets) welcomed Naruto into the family with open arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Sand Village and Leaf Village were in different nations, Shinobi are able leave and go to different villages as long as they do not abandon their duties in their previous village. Otherwise, they would be considered [Missing-Nin](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Missing-nin)

After the 2nd Great Ninja War, Tsunade retired from the Shinobi life and left Konoha.

> Leaving the village does not necessarily automatically make one a missing-nin. Tsunade withdraws from life as a ninja and departs from Konoha following the Second Shinobi World War

Temari and Shikamaru is not the first time we see Shinobi marriages from different villages. Naruto's Mother, [Kushina](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki), was originally from Uzushiogakure (Land Hidden in the Whirling Tides)

> Kushina Uzumaki was a Konohagakure kunoichi who originated from Uzushiogakure's 
>   Uzumaki clan
>
> ...
>
> Born into the famed Uzumaki clan of Uzushiogakure, Kushina lived most of her youth being caught up in war, making her seek for a daily peace. At a young age she was sent to Konoha and enrolled in the Academy

However [Uzushiogakure](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzushiogakure) was also apart of the Land of Fire, they were different villages.

Also, we *have* see other instances where Shinobi immigrated into other nations. One example is when [Jiraiya first used Rasengan against some gansters](https://youtu.be/Zr3PFfh3Uw4?t=16)

> The boss use to be a Chūnin from Hidden Village of the Stone

The [Hidden Village of the Stone](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Iwagakure) resides in the Land of Earth